# KeyError encountered even though keys exist

Tags: python, json

```
dir = {"sample":[
{ "key1":"data1" }

,
{ "key1":"data2" }

,
{ "key2":"data3" }

,
{ "key2":"data4" }
]
}
```

with my code:

```
listKey1 = []
listKey2 = []
with open(dir) as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
   for p in data['sample']:

        key1data = p['key1']
        print("key1: " + key1data)
        listKey1.append(key1data)
      
        key2data = p['key2']
        print("key2: " + key2data)
        listKey2.append(key2data)
```

Im trying to store the data under the key1 and key2 keys into the listKey1 and listKey2 but i am getting the error:

```
  KeyError: 'key1'
  KeyError: 'key2'
```

As we can see on my file that both key1 and key2 are present.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The first time through your list `p` will be `{ "key1":"data1" }`  it indeed does not have a key `key2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code. Just check if the key exists before using it.

```
listKey1 = []
listKey2 = []
with open(dir) as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
   for p in data['sample']:
        if "key1" in p.keys(): # check if key exists on the current index
            key1data = p['key1']
            print("key1: " + key1data)
            listKey1.append(key1data)
        if "key2" in p.keys(): # check if key exists on the current index
            key2data = p['key2']
            print("key2: " + key2data)
            listKey2.append(key2data)
```

Here is the output I get

```
key1: data1
key1: data2
key2: data3
key2: data4
```

Here is the reason why the key error occurs. Notice that there are different keys based on the index.

```
index [ 0 ] : { "key1":"data1" } - The key is "key1"-

,
index [ 1 ] :{ "key1":"data2" } - The key is "key1"

,
index [ 2 ] :{ "key2":"data3" } - The key is "key2"

,
index [ 3 ] :{ "key2":"data4" } - The key is "key2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that while you are looping p value does not always have `key1` or `key2`. It either has one or the other.

So when it finds `key1` it prints the data but gives an error for `key2`.
And when it finds `key2` it prints the data but gives an error for `key1`

A good option for you is to use the `get()` method. If the key is present it will return the value else it will give the default value.

Try the code below.

```
listKey1 = []
listKey2 = []
with open(dir) as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)
   for p in data['sample']:

        key1data = p.get('key1',"")
        print("key1: " + key1data)
        listKey1.append(key1data)
      
        key2data = p.get('key2',"")
        print("key2: " + key2data)
        listKey2.append(key2data)
```

Comment: the second argument of `.get()` sets the default you want in case the key is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the elements, compare by the `key` and store the data accordingly:

```
dd = {
      "sample":
        [
            { "key1":"data1" },
            { "key1":"data2" },
            { "key2":"data3" },
            { "key2":"data4" }
        ]
    }

key1data = []
key2data = []
for elem in dd['sample']:
    for key, val in elem.items():
        if key == "key1":
            key1data.append(elem.get("key1"))
        else:
            key2data.append(elem.get("key2"))

print(key1data)
print(key2data)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['data1', 'data2']                                                                                                                                                           
['data3', 'data4']
```